# Awk print first three folders in directory tree, separated by /

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk

I have a variable that prints a directory tree such as:

```
/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/folder5/folder6
```

I am only interested in the **first four values**, what would be the best way in bash to print only the first directories separated by backslash, such as:

```
/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4
```

Comment: Awk is probably not the best choice here, but: `awk  'BEGIN{FS=OFS="/"; }{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5}'`

Answer (score 8):

**Using awk:**

```
echo /folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/folder5/folder6 |\
    awk -F/ -vOFS=/ '{ print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5; }'
```

`OFS` = Output Field Separator.

`$1 .. $5` are required due to the leading slash counting as `1`.

**Using cut:**

```
echo /folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/folder5/folder6 |\
    cut -f -5 -d/
```

**Using sed:**

```
echo /folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/folder5/folder6 |\
    sed 's:\(\(/[^/]\+\)\{4\}\).*:\1:'
```

Comment: all in favour of **cut** here :)

Answer (score 2):

If there are **bash** and `var`iable

```
echo ${var%/${var#/*/*/*/*/}}
```

Other way

```
IFS=/ var=($var)
printf '%b/' "${var[@]::5}\n\c"
```